# XCode 8 signing product

Tags: code-signing, xcode8

I've just updated to XCode 8, I'm working with a old project ( probably created in XCode 6 or earlier ) the problem is (even in the simulator) XCode get stuck for at least half or one minute in the step signing product.

With XCode 7 the launch the app in the device was really fast, and there was not any Signing product phase.

Is there any way to make this process faster?

Because XCode includes the new feauture to help you to manage signatures and I tried to deactivate this in: Automatically manage signing. I still have the same problem.

I also tried with XCode 8.1 Beta

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I've discovered that this is happening because it's an old project. I worked with more recent projects and they work fine.